# Given $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. Does $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$ imply $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

Given $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. Does $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$ imply $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$?

Clearly this does not hold for $p = \infty$, since given functions with same hight, pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence. 
And when $p=1$, it becomes Scheffe's lemma.

For $ 1< p <\infty$, 
we have

$$\int |f_n - f|^p dm \leq 2^{p-1}\bigg(\int  |f_n|^p + |f|^p dm\bigg). $$
Using General Lebesgue Dominated Convergent theorem, we have 
$$\lim_n \int |f_n - f|^p dm = \int \lim_n |f_n - f|^p dm,$$
if and only if 
$$\lim_n \int |f_n|^p + |f|^p dm = \int \lim_n |f_n|^p + |f|^p dm$$
which holds from the assumption that $||f_n||_p \rightarrow ||f||_p$.

Is my argument correct? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I didn't see you were asking for a proof verification.

Comment: The first iequality is not true (there is a constant missing). I can't see why the second equality is true? Even if it were true, I don't see how you can finish the proof?

Comment: @Tomás I fixed the first one, forgot the constant from the convexity argument. The second one is from general dominated convergent theorem, give $f_n,g_n \rightarrow f,g$ a.e. and $|f_n|\leq g_n$, then $$\lim\int f_n = \int f \text{ only if } \lim \int g_n =\int g.$$ And wouldn't $$\lim \int|f_n - f|^p dm = 0$$ imply $||f_n - f||_p \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Ok, now I undertood, however I fail to see how would you conclude that $\lim\int |f_n-f|^p=0$?

Comment: @Tomas Thanks for the reply. Using general dominated convergence theorem, $$\lim\int |f_n - f|^p = \int\lim |f_n - f|^p = 0$$ since $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.